# Prove that if a function $f$ is such that $f'(x) \leq f(x)$ then it can be writen as $g(x)e^x$ with $g$ differentiable and nonincreasing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I'm stuck with this problem where I have to prove that every differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ for which for every $x$ in the domain $f'(x) \leq f(x)$, I have to prove that the function  belongs to the set $S=\left\{f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}; f(x) = g(x)e^x\right\}$ where $g(x)$ is a function $g:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ that belongs to the set of differentiable and nonincreasing functions.

As I see it this proof should have two parts, that is:

1. If a function is such that $f'(x) \leq f(x)$, then it belongs to the set $S$;
2. If a function belongs to the set $S$, then it's true that $f'(x) \leq f(x)$

Although the second part is simple to prove by taking the derivative of $g(x)e^x$ and using the definition of $g(x)$, the first part I am finding it rather difficult to prove. Help me!

Comment: You just have to show that $g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$ is non-increasing. And to do that, of course, you just have to differentiate it.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably overthinking this. If it were possible to find some $g$, it would clearly have to be $g(x) = f(x) \exp(-x)$. So consider this the definition of $g$.

Then $g$ is clearly differentiable since $f$ is, and we have $$\begin{align}g'(x) &= f'(x) \exp(-x) - f(x) \exp(-x) \\&= \exp(-x) (f'(x) - f(x)) \leq 0.\end{align}$$ So $g$ is non-increasing.

Comment: but then we are assuming that it's always possible to write f as g(x)exp(x). isn't this a problem?

Comment: @PedroBorges I'm saying "Define $g(x) = f(x) \exp(-x)$. Then $f(x) = g(x) \exp(x)$ and $g(x)$ is nonincreasing".

Answer (score 1):

Supppose $f>0$, ${f'\over{f}}\leq 1$ implies that $(Log(f(x))'\leq 1$ and $Log(f(x))\leq x+c$